# Authenticating a Blazor WebAssembly app with Azure Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've already got an existing Blazor WebAssembly app and I'm attempting to add authentication with Azure Active Directory.

I've added the `Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal` nuget.

In my server's `Program.cs`, I've added the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
            options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
        });
```

And I've added the following to my appsettings.json

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Domain": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
```

I'm struggling to understand what else I need to add so that when I run the app, I get the Microsoft sign in screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to require authorization for parts of the application, or for the entire app. By default, all routes inside the application are open to the public. If you want to shield any of these routes, you need to explicitly ask for authorization.
How to do this is documented here: [Secure ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

> In Blazor WebAssembly apps, authorization checks can be bypassed because all client-side code can be modified by users. The same is true for all client-side app technologies, including JavaScript SPA frameworks or native apps for any operating system.
>
> **Always perform authorization checks on the server within any API endpoints accessed by your client-side app.**

If you host the app on a hosting option like a Static Web App, you can have the Azure platform enforce authorization without having to implement anything manually.

[Authenticate and authorize Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new blazor web assemebly application and choose `Microsoft identity platform` and then modify the `appsettings.json` file.

[image]

You need to add 3 parts, authentication injection in `Program.cs`, configurations in `appsettings.json`, and the module for `sign view`, 2 of them you already had, and the left is the `sign in/out` button in the top navigation bar, so that you can click it to redirect to Microsoft sign in page. You can create the template project and copy the razor components into your project.

`LoginDisplay.razor`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject SignOutSessionStateManager SignOutManager

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginLogout">Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    private async Task BeginLogout(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();
        Navigation.NavigateTo("authentication/logout");
    }
}
```